# xamarin.andriod connect to web api

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am currently working on a Xamarin project for Mac and Android mobile devices. I am using Visual studio for mac to create the xamarin project. In my application I have to invoke a Webservice endpoint. As I am still at early stages; both the 
Webservice and the Xamarin mobile application are running locally on my machine. When I try to call the Webservice from Xamarin the base url works fine on mac as http://localhost:5000. However when I run android version, I am unable to connect to my local webservice using http://localhost:5000. Is there any workaround for this?

After researching, I have also tried using the following base uri's:

```
http://10.0.2.2:5000
```

I have also right-clicked on the project and under Build I went to Android Build. Underneath Code Generation and Runtime I selected Managed (HttpClientHandler) for the option HttpClient implementation. As well as SSL/TLS implementation for the option Native TLS 1.2+.

Comment: Well, it makes sense. When running on your local machine, localhost refers to your local machine. Now realize that you are running your code on a phone, either device or simulator. The scope changes: localhost will now be your mobile device. The API won't be running there, so localhost will not work. You will have to find out the IP address of your development machine, make sure the API runs, open up your firewall, etc. and connect to that address from your app.

Comment: Try opening the url with port number from a browser on the device first to make sure that the correct ports are open, etc.